# I changed the state value with setSate( ) in React, but it does not change immediately

Tags: reactjs, state, setstate

I wrote a function that changes the state value of the item when the button is clicked.
When I tried to change the changeItem value with the changed item value in the function, it was not applied.
When I checked the console.log inside and outside the function, the item value inside the function did not change immediately, but the previous value was confirmed.

```
//before pressing the button

function App() {
  const [item, setItem] = useState({
    name: "",
    color: "",
    size: 10
  })
  const [changeItem, setchangeItem] = useState(item);

  const onClickChangeItem = () => {
    setItem((prev) => ({
      ...prev,
      name: "haha",
      color: "blue",
      size: 30
    }));
    console.log(item);
    setchangeItem(item);
    console.log(changeItem);
  }
  console.log(item); // {name: '', color: '', size: 10}
  console.log(changeItem); // {name: '', color: '', size: 10}
  
  return (
    <div>
      <button onClick={onClickChangeItem}>change</button>
    </div>
  );
}

export default App;
```

```
//after pressing the button

function App() {
  const [item, setItem] = useState({
    name: "",
    color: "",
    size: 10
  })
  const [changeItem, setchangeItem] = useState(item);

  const onClickChangeItem = () => {
    setItem((prev) => ({
      ...prev,
      name: "haha",
      color: "blue",
      size: 30
    }));
    console.log(item); // {name: '', color: '', size: 10}
    setchangeItem(item); 
    console.log(changeItem);// {name: '', color: '', size: 10}
  }
  console.log(item); // {name: 'haha', color: 'blue', size: 30}
  console.log(changeItem); //{name: '', color: '', size: 10}
  
  return (
    <div>
      <button onClick={onClickChangeItem}>change</button>
    </div>
  );
}

export default App;
```

I want to apply the changed value of the item to the changeItem immediately when the button is pressed, but the previous value is applied over and over again.
How can I apply the changed value directly inside the function?

Answer (score 0):

There is two solutions to fix your issue

1- use setState callback to set changeItem just after the setItem

```js
//after pressing the button

function App() {
  const [item, setItem] = useState({
    name: "",
    color: "",
    size: 10
  })
  const [changeItem, setchangeItem] = useState(item);

  const onClickChangeItem = () => {
    setItem((prev) => ({
      ...prev,
      name: "haha",
      color: "blue",
      size: 30
    }), it => setchangeItem(it));

  }
  console.log(item); // {name: 'haha', color: 'blue', size: 30}
  console.log(changeItem); //{name: '', color: '', size: 10}
  
  return (
    <div>
      <button onClick={onClickChangeItem}>change</button>
    </div>
  );
}

export default App;
```

2- add a useEffect that will be executed everytime the item is changed
your code will look like that

```js
function App() {
  const [item, setItem] = useState({
    name: "",
    color: "",
    size: 10
  })
  const [changeItem, setchangeItem] = useState(item);

useEffect(() => {
 setchangeItem(item)
}, [item])

  const onClickChangeItem = () => {
    setItem((prev) => ({
      ...prev,
      name: "haha",
      color: "blue",
      size: 30
    }));
    console.log(item); // {name: '', color: '', size: 10}
    console.log(changeItem);// {name: '', color: '', size: 10}
  }
  console.log(item); // {name: 'haha', color: 'blue', size: 30}
  console.log(changeItem); //{name: '', color: '', size: 10}
  
  return (
    <div>
      <button onClick={onClickChangeItem}>change</button>
    </div>
  );
}

export default App;
```

Comment: Thanks for your reply. Solution 1 was found to be applied only to the class component.
It was confirmed that the changeItem value did not change when solution 2 was applied.
Is there any other way to apply the changed value directly inside the onClickChangeItem function?

Comment: @JuhuiKim    Both solution should work fine I tested that on codeSandbox . I recommand to use the solution 2 React team implemented useEffect hook to solve this issues why you don't want to use it ?

Comment: I was wondering if it is possible to apply the changed state value directly within the button click function. Thank you for your reply.

Comment: @JuhuiKim The only way to do that is to use the callback as i mentionned in solution 1 otherwise we need useEffect and i recommend to use useEffect.

Comment: Thank you for answer. It really helped a lot.

Answer (score -1):

The easiest way to accomplish this would be to get rid of the `changeItem` state. When you set the state of `item`, it is changing just fine. You can just work with that.

If you want to keep your code the way you have it, then you would need a useEffect. That way, you can update `changeItem` every time `item` changes:

```
import { useEffect } from 'react'

useEffect(() => {
setChangeItem(item);
}, [item])
```